# Issue to pass table name as parameter to a SqlCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-6.0

The goal of this issue is avoid SQL injection, I have queries (select, insert, update, delete).

When I need to send the table name as parameter, how can I do that? I will really appreciate your help.

```
insertCommand.CommandText = "update @tableName set code = @code where rowid = @ID";
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tableName", table.Name));
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@code", table.code));
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", table.id));
```

Comment: You can't pass the table name as a parameter, you need to use dynamic SQL if you want to do that.

Comment: Usually, trying to parameterise a table name is an indication that a mistake has been made in the data modelling, and what you should instead have is a single table with one or more additional columns containing the data that has currently been embedded in the table names

Comment: You can build a string with dynamic table name in it. If you want to prevent injection, you can make a whitelist of tablenames to check your dynamic table name parameter against.

Comment: @tozlu do you have any example to do that?

Comment: @sesesese posted an answer with example

Comment: I assume you are aware of and are comfortable with the fact your command is named with the _insert_ prefix even though it is performing an `UPDATE` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use parameter as a table name. However if you want to use dynamic table name and also prevent injection. You can create a white list of table names and check your dynamic parameter against the list.

Here is an example.

```cs
public void UpdateDynamicTable(string tableName, string code, string rowid){

  var listOfAllowedTableNames = new List<string>{
    "Vehicles", "Departments", "Companies"
  };
  if(!listOfAllowedTableNames.Contains(tableName){
    return; //You can return 400 (Bad Request) if its a web app
  }
  var updateCommand = ... //construct the command
  updateCommand.CommandText = $"UPDATE {tableName} SET code = @code WHERE rowid = @id";
  updateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@code", code));
  updateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", rowid));
  // fire the update and return ...
}
```

Comment: This approach is an OCP violation. Not saying that that irreversibly excludes it as a possible approach, but it's not a _great_ one either.

Comment: Well it's not a code for use in a strictly principle focused production application, neither I'm responsible for providing such an answer. It's for showing the OP that there are other ways for achieving what they asked.

Comment: If the table name NEVER comes from user input, then I don't see how this is any problem. The vast majority of sql command objects are free form sql - the fact that this uses parameters - quite much most code works like this. I mean for every single sql command in a application I don't think it warrants a store procedure for each such case. As long as the inputs from user input are parameters as this shows, then I fail to see why this is a problem? I mean EF, or datasets don't setup store proces - they JUST submit sql with params to sql server and THAT is what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use a parameter as the table name reference, but we can validate the table name against the current database *before* executing your query.

This method of sanitisation adds an additional request to the database, but is lightweight and easier to maintain than solutions that involve *Stored Procedures* as it keeps the data query logic within your application code (C#) and doesn't require all tables to be previously whitelisted.

```
string chkTableSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = @table";
SqlCommand chkTable = new SqlCommand(chkTableSQL, conn);
chkTable.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
chkTable.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@table", tableName));
var rows = (int?)chkTable.ExecuteScalar();

if(rows.GetValueOrDefault() == 0)
    throw new ArgumentException($"Table '{tableName}' not found.", nameof(tableName));
```

After that has been executed, it should be safe to use the `tableName` parameter value in your constructed SQL Command.

To make it easier, you could package the above code into it's own method for re-use:
*NOTE: this method is designed specifically to throw an exception instead of returning a boolean state, this pattern makes it easier to drop into existing code without creating new `if` blocks, change this to match your preferred coding paradigm*

```
/// <summary>
/// Check the current database connection for the existence of the specified table
/// Throws an exception if the table does not exist.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tableName">The name of the table to check against the specified <paramref name="conn"/></param>
/// <param name="conn">SQL Connection to query for the existence of the <paramref name="tableName"/></param>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Throws exception when the <paramref name="tableName"/> was not found.</exception>
public void VerifyTableName(string tableName, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn)
{
    string chkTableSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE [TABLE_NAME] WHERE [name] = @table";
    var chkTableCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(chkTableSQL, conn);
    chkTableCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    chkTableCommand.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@table", tableName));
    var rows = (int?)chkTableCommand.ExecuteScalar();

    if (rows.GetValueOrDefault() == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException($"Table '{tableName}' not found.", nameof(tableName));
}
```

So now we can use this in the original code block, note that the table name has been escaped in this script as well as the column names, this is more about getting into the habbit of it more than anything else, especially given that we have already verified the table name:

```
VerifyTableName(table.Name, insertCommand.Connection);
insertCommand.CommandText = $"update [{table.Name}] set [code] = @code where [rowid] = @ID";
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tableName", table.Name));
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@code", table.code));
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", table.id));
```

> **NOTE:** Solutions that involve Dynamic SQL Generation or Deliberate Injection should be avoided for all sorts of reasons, SQL injection attacks are just one reason. There are usually better designs, methodologies or ORMs that can solve these sorts of problems in different ways.

### UPDATE

Thanks to [Caius Jard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410664/caius-jard) for pointing out `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as a better solution than MS SQL Server specific `SYS.TABLES`. It is an ANSI standard set of views that is supported in many RDBMS as listed in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema).

I personally rarely have need to query the Information Schema directly however it provides a more platform agnostic solution to querying database structures when needed.

Comment: Teaching use of INFORMATION_SCHEMA would make this technique more cross-db portable

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard Thats good advice, another reason that is better advice is that `View` names will be included in the lookup as well and that might be useful for OP, in this context _Views_ and _Tables_ could easily be referenced.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot as the table name has to be available at SQL "compile time". The workaround is to use dynamic query approach. You practically build your query as string and execute it inside the procedure, so you can use your table name as parameter.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure

However I highly recommend not to do so as you will end up with complex and unsustainable application

Comment: OP is specifically worried about SQL Injection and is already dynamically constructing the SQL Statement, moving that construction into a Stored Procedure assists with parameterising the table name but you've already stated this adds an additional layer of complexity and as such it is not a good solution to this specific issue.